# Same zooming in 2 scrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I am working on Pic Collage type of application. I have two scrollviews as shown in the figure below. [image]

I have used this code to create an image to save in gallery

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return resultingImage;
```

But this creates an image of 320 X 460 resolution image which is not good for sharing or adding as a profile or cover photo on facebook/twitter etc.

This is why I tried to create everything programmatically when user clicks on Done. The only problem that I am facing is I am not able to get the same zoom scale here. When I am creating everything again programmatically, the scroll view should be zoomed so that when I combine the view for 640 X 960 resolution image, the scrollview subview i.e. image should also look like what user has set in the scrolls. Here is the code:

[image]

```
UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 960)];
        [mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 290, 920)];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [mainView addSubview:scrollView];

    UIScrollView *scrollView11 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(330, 20, 290, 920)];
    [scrollView11 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [mainView addSubview:scrollView11];

    [scrollView1.layer setBorderWidth:0.0];
    [scrollView2.layer setBorderWidth:0.0];

    [[[scrollView1 subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    [[[scrollView2 subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];


    [scrollView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 290, 920)];
    [scrollView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(330, 20, 290, 920)];

    UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 100)];
    [imgV setImage:[self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"] width:1166 height:960]];
    //[imgV sizeToFit];
    [scrollView1 addSubview:imgV];

    UIImageView *imgV1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 100)];
    [imgV1 setImage:[self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.png"] width:846 height:960]];
    //[imgV1 sizeToFit];
    [scrollView2 addSubview:imgV1];

    scrollView1.contentSize = imgV.image.size;
    scrollView2.contentSize = imgV1.image.size;

    NSLog(@"scrollview subviews - %@",[scrollView1 subviews]);

    [self initScrollView:scrollView1];
    [self initScrollView:scrollView2];

    [self centerScrollViewContents:scrollView1 withImageView:imgV];
    [self centerScrollViewContents:scrollView2 withImageView:imgV1];

    CGFloat newZoomScale = scrollView1.zoomScale;

    // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
    CGSize scrollViewSize = scrollView1.bounds.size;

    CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat x = point.x - (w / 2.0f);
    CGFloat y = point.y - (h / 2.0f);

    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*2, rect.origin.y*2, rect.size.width*2, rect.size.height*2);
    CGRect rectToZoom = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [scrollView1 zoomToRect:rectToZoom animated:YES];




     newZoomScale = scrollView2.zoomScale;

    // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
     scrollViewSize = scrollView2.bounds.size;

     w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
     h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
     x = point1.x - (w / 2.0f);
     y = point1.y - (h / 2.0f);

    rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(rect1.origin.x*2, rect1.origin.y*2, rect1.size.width*2, rect1.size.height*2);
    rectToZoom = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [scrollView2 zoomToRect:rectToZoom animated:YES];

    [mainView addSubview:scrollView1];
    [mainView addSubview:scrollView2];

    [scrollView1.layer setBorderWidth:0.0];
    [scrollView2.layer setBorderWidth:0.0];
```

Please help.
Thanks in Advance!